# Need help with a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Please help me with this MySQL query. I've been on it for long enough. Perhaps it needs a fresh pair of eyes.

Two tables: **locks** and **sessions**

```
locks
--------------
id session_id
--------------
1  sajf4$Jf9422jd
2  2jf*4j2okg9092
3  J8j4j4ffss93o2
------------------

sessions
-------------------------
id              user_id
-------------------------
sajf4$Jf9422jd  14
J8j4j4ffss93o2  14
2jf*4j2okg9092  21
-------------------------
```

I want to delete all rows in locks where user_id of session = 14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM locks 
WHERE session_id IN (SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE user_id = 14)
```

Comment: DELETE FROM locks 
WHERE session_id **IN** (SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE user_id = 14) 
but close enough

Answer (score 2):

DELETE FROM `locks` WHERE `session_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `sessions` WHERE `user_id` = 14);

Answer (score 2):

delete from locks where session_id in (select_id from sessions where user_id =14)

Answer (score 1):

Another way without a subquery:

delete from locks
 using locks
 join sessions on sessions.id=locks.session_id
 where sessions.user_id=14

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE locks, sessions FROM locks INNER JOIN sessions WHERE locks.session_id=sessions.id;
```